# How to set up a custom Quota's object? (multiple quotas)

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, reporting, process-builder, joined-reports

I'm looking for some folks to help me brainstorm how to set up a custom object(s) to allow managers to input quotas for sales people. I can't use the OOTB forecast/quota functionality because it only allows for a single quota, whereas I need to be able to show 2 quotas: a mandatory goal, and a "stretch" goal.

Visually I had the following in mind:

A spreadsheet-like page with a list of sales people and their profile image in column 1, then each month of the year in the top row. In each "cell" would be two inputs: goal and stretch goal. The manager would be able to input $ into both cells for each sales person, hit "save" or some button, and this would save into a custom object.

I would then need to be able to represent this in a report/dashboard that shows total opportunities along with the goals the sales person needs to reach.

**Thoughts on how to best set up the object(s) for this?**

I'm thinking the visual aspect would be best represented in a visualforce page but I can't fathom how after clicking "save", the data would get pushed/edited into the object. I'm also struggling with how to join this with the opportunity object for reporting.

I'm comfortable setting up visualforce and flow pages but the schema of how this would work is so lost on me. **Help!**

**if you respond to this question, I will reward you by sending good vibes through the interwebs**

Comment: for perspective --- [this 13 year old Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqENAA0); the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.forecasts3_overview.htm&type=5) says you can have 4 types of forecasts, each with its own quota - does that help?

Comment: @cropredy you can have different quotas for different product types etc. but not for revenue from opportunities -- that only allows a single quota.